# How do I store a function to a variable?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I think they are called functors? (it's been a while)

Basically, I want to store a pointer to a function in a variable, so I can specify what function I want to use from the command line.

all the functions return and take the same values.

```
unsigned int func_1 (unsigned int var1)
unsigned int func_2 (unsigned int var1)

function_pointer = either of the above?
```

so then I could call it by going: `function_pointer(my_variable)?`

EDIT: 
as per @larsmans's suggestion, I've gotten this:
Config.h:

```
class Config
{
public:
    unsigned static int (*current_hash_function)(unsigned int);
};
```

Config.cpp:

```
#include "Config.h"
#include "hashes.h"
unsigned static int (*current_hash_function)(unsigned int) = kennys_hash_16;
```

hashes.h:

```
unsigned int kennys_hash(unsigned int out);
unsigned int kennys_hash_16(unsigned int out);
```

hashes.cpp:

```
just implements the functions in the header
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "Config.h"
#include "hashes.h"
// in test_network:
    unsigned int hashed = Config::current_hash_function(output_binary);

//in main():
        else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-kennys_hash_16") == 0)
        {
            Config::current_hash_function = kennys_hash_16;
        }
        else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-kennys_hash_8") == 0)
        {
            Config::current_hash_function = kennys_hash;
        }
```

the error I get:

```
g++ -o hPif src/main.o src/fann_utils.o src/hashes.o src/Config.o -lfann -L/usr/local/lib 
Undefined symbols:
  "Config::current_hash_function", referenced from:
      test_network()     in main.o // the place in the code I've selected to show
      auto_test_network_with_random_data(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)in main.o
      generate_data(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)in main.o
      _main in main.o // the place in the code I've selected to show
      _main in main.o // the place in the code I've selected to show
      generate_train_file()     in fann_utils.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hPif] Error 1
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The simplest you can do is

```
unsigned int (*pFunc)(unsigned int) = func_1;
```

This is a bare function pointer, which cannot be used to point to anything other than a free function.

You can make it less painful if your compiler supports the C++0x `auto` keyword:

```
auto pFunc = func_1;
```

In any case, you can call the function with

```
unsigned int result = pFunc(100);
```

There are many other options that provide generality, for example:

- You can use `boost::function` with any C++ compiler
- With a compiler implementing features of C++0x you can use `std::function`

These can be used to point to any entity that can be invoked with the appropriate signature (it's actually objects that implement an `operator()` that are called functors).

### Update (to address updated question)

Your immediate problem is that you attempt to use `Config::current_hash_function` (which you declare just fine) but fail to define it.

This defines a global static pointer to a function, unrelated to anything in `class Config`:

```
unsigned static int (*current_hash_function)(unsigned int) = kennys_hash_16;
```

This is what you need instead:

```
unsigned int (*Config::current_hash_function)(unsigned int) = kennys_hash_16;
```

Comment: In c++0x one can use `auto` ;-)

Comment: how do I assign the function to pFunc, and how do I call pFunc?

Comment: @DerNalia: There is code for both how to assign, and how to call the function.

Comment: So, then.. I think my error has to do with How I'm using classes then. I'll mark this as the answer, and upvote you. If you could help my classing problem, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 10):

From C++11 you can use `std::function` to store functions. To store function you use it as follsonig:

> std::function<*return type*(*parameter type(s)*)>

as an example here it is:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int fact (int a) {
    return a > 1 ? fact (a - 1) * n : 1;
}

int pow (int b, int p) {
    return p > 1 ? pow (b, p - 1) * b : b;
}

int main (void) {
    std::function<int(int)> factorial = fact;
    std::function<int(int, int)> power = pow;

    // usage
    factorial (5);
    power (2, 5);
}
```

Comment: Why does main have `void` and doesn't return anything? (Otherwise great answer)

Comment: In C if you have main () it will accept as many arguments as you want, and is some cases it will keep those arguments for as long as program is running. void guaranties main it will automatically discard all arguments that you give it.

Comment: here is the good read. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-int-main-int-mainvoid/

Answer (score 4):

No, these are called function pointers.

```
unsigned int (*fp)(unsigned int) = func_1;
```

Comment: Note: you're going to call it as `(*fp)(my_variable)`, not the way it is described in the post.

Comment: @Michael: you can call with `fp(arg)` as it the function pointer were an ordinary function. Try it out.

Comment: I think I'm really close... however, I'm getting symbol not found. I'm storing the function pointer in a different class... I'll add some code.

Comment: @DerNalia: That's because you're declaring the function pointer as an instance variable, not a static member, so you can't set it on the class itself. If you want it to be a class-wide setting, for syntactic sanity, I would typedef the function-pointer type and then create a static member with that typedef for its type.

Comment: what does typedefing mean? (i'm new to C++, if you can't tell ^_~)

Comment: also, I wish I could select multiple answers as right... cause... it's unfair to people the way it is, ya know?

Answer (score 4):

You could also use function either from the c++0x or from boost.
That would be

```
boost::function<int(int)>
```

and then use bind to bind your function to this type.

Have a look [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/function/tutorial.html) and [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/bind/bind.html)

Ok here would be a example. I hope that helps.

```
int MyFunc1(int i)
{
    std::cout << "MyFunc1: " << i << std::endl;
    return i;
}

int MyFunc2(int i)
{
    std::cout << "MyFunc2: " << i << std::endl;
    return i;
}

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/)
{
    typedef boost::function<int(int)> Function_t;

    Function_t myFunc1 = boost::bind(&MyFunc1, _1);
    Function_t myFunc2 = boost::bind(&MyFunc2, _1);

    myFunc1(5);
    myFunc2(6);
}
```

Comment: This is all kinda confusing.... so if I have a function called "my_function", how do I assign it to a variable, so I can call it by doing "function_pointer(variable)"?

Comment: I understand you code but can you tell me typedef boost:function<int(int)> Function_t work or how you use <int(int)>?

Answer (score 3):

You can store a function in a variable in c++ in this way

```
auto function_name = [&](params){
    statements 
};


auto add = [&](int a,int b){
    return a+b;
};
cout<<add(5,6);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef unsigned int (*PGNSI)(unsigned int);

PGNSI variable1 = func_1;
PGNSI variable2 = func_2;
```

Comment: I do not understand can I use pointer like class where variable one and two store other functions?

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int (* myFuncPointer)(unsigned int) = &func_1;
```

However, the syntax for function pointers is awful, so it's common to `typedef` them:

```
typedef unsigned int (* myFuncPointerType)(unsigned int);
myFuncPointerType fp = &func_1;
```

Comment: This is all kinda confusing.... so if I have a function called "my_function", how do I assign it to a variable, so I can call it by doing "function_pointer(variable)"  thanks. =\

Answer (score -1):

IF you have [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/more/getting_started/index.html) installed, you can also check out [Boost Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/function/tutorial.html).

Comment: Did you see the examples given in the Boost Function link? For e.g., in your case the functions take an `unsigned int` and returns an `unsigned int`. If you use Boost Function, then you will have to declare `boost::function1<unsigned int, unsigned int> f;`. What this means is, you are declaring a function object `f` which returns an `unsigned int` (the first template parameter) and takes in an `unsigned int` as parameter (the second template parameter). So if you have a function like `void fx(int, int)` then you declare the function object as `boost::function2<void, int, int> f`.

Comment: The above comment is about how to declare the function object. Then in the code where you want to use it, all you have to do is, `f = &your_function;`. Then at the call site you just invoke `f(3)`. See the Boost Function tutorial. Its very self explanatory.

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli: The answer isn't invalid just because its confusing to follow the syntax in the article.