# Need to assign function to variable in C++

Tags: c++, function, variables, unordered-map, auto

this shouldn't be too hard but I am stuck.

I am trying to assign a function to a variable but I need to know the data type so I can assign it to a map.

I was successful doing this:

```
auto pfunc = Ext::SomeFunction
```

This will then allow me to do:

```
pfunc(arg, arg2);
```

But I need to know what data type is being covered by "auto" so I can map my functions to a string.

For example:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, "datatype"> StringToFunc = {{"Duplicate", Ext::Duplicate}};
```

Most of these functions return void but there are other functions that returns double and int.

If there is a better way of doing this please let me know but I would really like to know the data type behind the auto as used above.

Thanks much for any help received.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Comment: Is `Ext` a type or a namesapce?  I ask because non-static member functions are not the same as global/namespace functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: How do I store a function to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582869/c-how-do-i-store-a-function-to-a-variable)

Comment: @NathanOliver it is a namespace that has the class being called.

Comment: So `SomeFunction` is not a class member function, right?

Comment: My bad, it is a class member function. Ext is the parent class. For example class Ext { public: SomeFunction() { //...} }

Comment: I did some debugging in VS and this is the type pfunc came back to: void(*)(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the typedef and unordered_map below:

```
typedef void(*StringFunc)(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >);
std::unordered_map<std::string, StringFunc> StringToAction = {
    {"Buy", Car::BuyCar}, {"Fix", Car::FixCar}
};
```

Comment: This works too: typedef void(*StringFunc)(std::string);

Answer (score 5):

Given a `class foo` and a member function `fun`, you can create a member function pointer in the following manner:

```
struct foo 
{
    void fun(int, float);
};

void(foo::*fptr)(int, float) = &foo::fun;
```

So the type of `fptr` would be `void(foo::*)(int, float)`. Usually with something like this you might want to introduce a `typedef` or type alias to make the declaration more readable:

```
using function = void(foo::*)(int, float);
// or typedef void(foo::*function)(int, float);
function fptr = &foo::fun;
```

*In addition*, the above applies for member function pointers. For free functions the syntax would be:

```
void fun(int, float);
void(*fptr)(int, float) = &fun;
```

And you can define your type alias accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need type erasure for function objects and `std::function` implements that for you.

```
#include<functional>
#include<unordered_map>
... define f1
... define f2
int main(){
   std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<ret_type(arg1_type, arg2_type)>> um = {{"name1", f1}, {"name2", f2}};
}
```