# Is there a way to store methods in some type of vector in c++?

Tags: c++, image, vector, chaining, juce

This is my first time here.

I'm currently trying to write a class for post-processing images by going through all pixels and doing stuff to the colours there.

My idea is to add methods like `posterize()` or `rgbSplit()` etc. When they are initialized it won't go through all pixels for each effect because that's not very performant. I want it to kind of store the fact that it should process these effects in the given chain later when I use a method called `process()`.

But therefore I'd have to kinda store the reference to the effects' code in a list (like a vector), right? Because then I could go into the `for`-loop of the x and y-coordinates and add another for-loop there that goes through all methods that should be applied to the pixels.

The problem is, I have no idea how to store a method in a vector. Is that even possible? or are vectors only for objects? Or can I somehow "objectify" a method? Or what would be the thing that I have to do now?

Comment: yes. Please show your code. Code described in english is extremely hard to understand

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I store a function to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582869/how-do-i-store-a-function-to-a-variable)

Comment: @idclev463035818 No need for code here the question is clear

Comment: You could wrap the vector with a class, add methods to the class, operate the vector by calling class methods

Comment: ok i guess i have to learn how to use the so called "function pointers" then, am i right? i just tried some stuff and it gave me errors but i think i'll keep on trying different stuff before asking you more questions. thank you for your help so far!

Answer (score 5):

This question is very broad. But I understand that you are at the beginning, and need to know if it's possible, before writing some code.

So here a quick low-level answer:

- yes you can have vectors of [function pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer);
- yes you can have vectors of [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), which is much more powerful and flexible than raw function pointers;
- yes you can "objectify" a method by putting it as virtual function in a class and using it as if it were a function (either using a method name and implementing a [command pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/command-pattern.html), or using `operator()` to implement a classical [functor](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/functors-in-cpp/)).
- yes you can even chain in a more flexible way your different raster operations, by replacing the array with a variant of the [chain of responsibility pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/chain-of-responsibility-pattern.html)

But at a higher level, you need to better think about your design:

- some image filters can work at a pixel level, and then your approach is fine
- but some image filter work on a group of adjacent pixels.  If you would work pixel by pixel,  the chaining would not work properly, since there will be alredy transformed pixels and still original untransformed pixels in the groups that are processed.

So your design needs to cope with both kind of algorithms.  For example you could first apply the preliminary pixel transformation in the chain to all the pixels, then only run the algorithm on the groups of already transformed pixels, then continue in the chain.

Moreover,  as [Daniel McLaury](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2462437/daniel-mclaury) pointed out in the comments, an additional question is whether it makes sense from a performance point of view to call an algorithm pixel by pixel.  Maybe chaining algorithms is a good idea, but at the image transformation level and not the pixel level.

Once you have thought about this, and started implementing a solution with one of the above mentioned ideas, you may come back here with more precise questions, illustrated with some code.

Comment: Also, even if you want to loop over all pixels and do X, Y, Z to each pixel, it's not inherently more performant to loop over all the pixels once and do X, Y, and Z than it is to loop over the pixels three separate times.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury this is indeed a very relevant remark! Instead of one call to process a millions of pixels, we have a million of calls to process one pixels. Many thanks for pointing it out ! I've edited accordingly (of course with attribution)

Comment: good point about the design stuff. i already had the same thought. my idea about this is that when an image is referenced to the process function then in this function a new image is created and all processing kinda goes from the referenced image to the new image. when all loops ended i do image = newImage to bring it back to the actual image. that's why i think that my implementation is ok so far. but yeah, as you correctly said i am a beginner. so i could be wrong about everything i do

Comment: @FlorianMrugalla No problem. Experimentation is the best teacher!

Answer (score 0):

if the observer pattern is intended, then boost::signals2 is a good candidate.

Observer pattern
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern?wprov=sfla1

boost::signals2
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/signals2.html

Cheers,
FM.

Answer (score 0):

i'm currently following the tutorial of the cherno on function pointers because i thought maybe i need someone who goes through it in detail and extremely well structured. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4sDgQ-jao4&t=306s

at 5min he made a function pointer by saying void(*cherno)() = HelloWorld;

i tried to do that as well but get an error. here's my code:

```
class ImagePP {
public:
    ImagePP() { }

    void someFunc() { DBG("someFunc started"); }

    void process() {
        DBG("process Started.");

        void(*function)() = someFunc;
        function;
    }
private:

};
```

it underlines someFunc and the error says:

a value of type "void (ImagePP::*)()" can not be used to initialize an entity of type "void(*)()"

---

if i understand it right it says i can't do that because i'm not doing it in main, but in a class. but what can i do about it then? i want to use it in this class

Comment: instance member functions are different from static functions. As a newbie, you start with  std:: function and lambda.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ImagePP {
public:
    std::function<void> someFunc(int i) { DBG("someFunc started: " << i); }

    void process() {
        DBG("process Started.");

        typedef std::function<void>(ImagePP::*FuncPtr)(int);
        FuncPtr function = someFunc;
        function(5);
    }
};
```

this is what i got now. realized it wants the class name there, but now it underlines (5) even though the function wants an integer. it says:

expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type

i have the same error when i use normal void instead of std::function